# How to change the location of a Button in a Panel?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, button, panel

i am trying to perform some operation in a panel based on my needs and changing the location of the existing added buttons to new locations.

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
{   
   protected override OnPaint()
   {  
       // Added the controls.


       // Done some operations which needs the location change.


       // Changed the location of the buttons.

   }

 }
```

But the controls are not visible in the panel.

COntrols are properly shown in the panel only when the locations are not changed.

**Does any one please let me know, why the controls are not shown in the panel when changing the location dynamically ?**

Comment: can you add code in `OnPaint` method?

Comment: Why are you trying to add controls in the `OnPaint` method?

Comment: Show the code that performs these operations instead of comments. And, as already asked, explain how the `OnPaint()` event comes into play here.

Comment: Never do anything in a Paint event that will enforce painting! An infinite loop is the result!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your project

```
Control board = panel1;

Button But = new Button()
{
     Size = new Size(size, size),
     Location = new Point(x, y),
     ....
};

board.Controls.Add(But);
```